# Array index out of Bound exception for a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I am declaring a 2D array with column size as zero.while taking the input i am getting array index out of bound exception. I don't understand why?

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int arr[][]=new int[3][0];

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{

    for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
    {
        arr[i][j]=s.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: then what is the use of creating 2d array?

Comment: i was just checking if we can declare a 2d array like this which will have a zero column.

Comment: yes you can since you know it has 0 columns then how does it works for `for(int j=0;j<1;j++)` column for loop think

Comment: i think a 2d array will have atleast 1 column.i guess 2d array with a 0 column is not possible.Probably that's where i was wrong in the declaration part

Comment: remove that for loop `for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
    {
        arr[i][j]=s.nextInt();
    }` and run the program it will get executed, you can declare 2d array like this `int arr[][]=new int[3][0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with:

```
int arr[][]=new int[3][1];
```

If you want an array of length one, you should declare it as:

```
new int[1];
```

This would create an array that can hold one element, at index 0.

Comment: i guess by length u mean number of rows right.??but i want 3 rows there

Comment: The declaration 'new int[3][1]' will create a matrix with 3 rows and 1 column.

Comment: ooo..yes..i got it now..i was declaring it with index 0.but row and column size should be 1 more than the index .

Comment: Yes, arrays in Java start from index 0, so for example an array of length 2 will be able to store two elements, at indexes 0 and 1. If you try to store something at index 2 you will get an out of bounds exception, since allowing you to do that would require an array of size 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes use of 0th column so you need to declare one column in the declaration

```
int[][] arr = new int[3][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

change j<1 to j<0     `

```
for(int j=0;j<0;j++)
{
    arr[i][j]=s.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: It will not be able to collect input then.it will get terminated